# Web Page - Firefox, Chrome vs Microsoft Edge

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, css, microsoft-edge, html5

I have created a WebPage, working from NotePad++, and then uploading to 'my site':   www.marioninhsgbbstats.com
My problem is with the navigation menu.  It (my Index and CSS file) works fine when I run my work from NotePad to Firefox and to Chrome.
When I run the URL on Firefox and Chrome it works fine.  (Yes, there are a couple of problems, but I expect to be able to correct them.

When I go to Microsoft Edge, I run into problems.  minor-my right arrow shows differently.

Major concern:  When I go to 'Year by Year', and go down to 'Varsity TEAM year by year' there should be a listing of 4, and then sublistings that show when 1 of the 4 arrowed topics is selected.  (Again appears to work fine in FireFox and Chrome.)

Microsoft edge is showing all 'listings' in 1 vertical list immediately, and then 1 of 4 is selected, choices show below, instead of off to the side as desired (and shows in FireFox and Chrome).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I did have a similar problem, but using classes seemed to solve the problem.
I just went back to NotePad, and tried running on IE, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better question to ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). But what you need to do is have your code figure out if the browser in use is Edge, and make modifications from there to your webpage's UI. Hope this helps!